# How to restart node app (typescript) when using supervisor?

Tags: node.js

I have a NodeJS server written in Typescript, and I'm using supervisor to run this app in the background in production. However, when I type `supervisorctl stop myapp`, the process stops, but the node process is still running in the background and the site is live. How do I stop the given nodejs process with supervisor?

Comment: right now I have to do ```sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:9001````

Answer (score 0):

If supervisorctl stop doesn't stop your node process, you can actually set the stopsignal to one of following values: QUIT, KILL

In the config file '/etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf' add the following:

```
stopsignal=KILL
```

For more details check [this](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=stopsignal#program-x-section-settings).